# Creating threads from generic lambdas with references as generic parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

How can I create a thread using a generic lambda with auto parameters defined as reference?

For instance, what would be the right way to achieve something conceptually equivalent to this:

```
int vi = 0;
auto lambda = [](auto &v) {};
auto t = std::thread(lambda, std::ref(vi));
```

gcc-5.3 complains because of the missing type:

```
/opt/gcc/el6/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<main()::<lambda(auto:2&)>(std::reference_wrapper<int>)>’:
/opt/gcc/el6/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/thread:137:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = main()::<lambda(auto:2&)>&; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<int>}]’
testLambdaCapture.cpp:52:41:   required from here
/opt/gcc/el6/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<main()::<lambda(auto:2&)>(std::reference_wrapper<int>)>’
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
/opt/gcc/el6/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<main()::<lambda(auto:2&)>(std::reference_wrapper<int>)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

As a side question, why does it work when the generic parameter is passed by value like this:

```
auto lambda = [](auto v) {};
auto t = std::thread(lambda, vi);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed:

```
#include <thread>

int vi = 0;
auto lambda = [](auto &&v) {};
auto t = std::thread(lambda, std::ref(vi)); 

// this works too
auto rv = std::ref(vi);
auto t2 = std::thread(lambda, rv);
```

In this case, auto&& is being deduced as if it were a template argument. Hence the actual type during instantiation is either `const T&` or `T&&` as required.

Comment: Yes, it is actually a good illustration why `auto& ` seldom makes sense. It is either `auto ` or `auto &&`.

Comment: @SergeyA do you have any meaningful example where auto& would make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it tries to deduce `auto&` from an rvalue of type `std::reference_wrapper<int>` and fails to do so, since non-const lvalue references can't be deduced from rvalues. Only when the target function either has a reference to a known type (meaning no deduction, and `reference_wrapper`'s conversion operator applies) or a non-reference type (meaning no conversion necessary) does it work.

Comment: According to your statement, it sounds like `std::thread([](int &v) {}, std::ref(vi));` shouldn't work either. Did I misread something?

Comment: @ComeRaczy, yes, you did misread. In your example there is no **deduction**, but just a conversion from `std::ref` to the lvalue reference, which works fine.